# Swift change notification body

Tags: swift, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, swift2

I have a remote notification via GCM like this.

```
    Notification received: [aps: {
    alert =     {
        body = "Test body";
        title = "Test title";
    };
}, gcm.message_id: 0:1452513835656563%81fe7d7d81fe7d7d]
```

I need to change "body" receiving message because my app has got multi language function. How can I achieve this? Do I need to parse it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

As your application support multi language function so you need to make your custom notification based on your language.

For more information please look into the [Notifications and data in the message payload](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=en) for how to make the custom notification.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hello Nikita, Please add relevant data from the said link to improve quality and reliability of your answer  (In case the link changes some day)

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I have added the link for official google developer link which I thought did not change frequently.

Comment: thank you for response but i have no clue what to do. The google tutorial does not provide answer for my issue.

Comment: As you want to change the receiving message of "body" instead of you can add your new key-value pair in "data" section based on the multi language. For ie. {....
"data" : { "language" : "spanish" "title" : "", "desc" : "" },  }